# HttpClient MultipartFormDataContent with parameters (C#)

Tags: c#, csv, httpclient

I am trying send a csv file and parameters to a http API and am struggling to debug what is going wrong.

For POST requests that require parameters only (no csv file) then I can successfully do this:

```
    HttpContent upload = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "name", "myName" }});
    HttpResponseMessage uploadResponse = await client.PostAsync("api/datasets", upload);
```

For POST requests that require parameters and a csv file I am using MultipartFormDataContent:

```
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            HttpContent upload = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "name", "myName" }});            
            content.Add(upload);

            byte[] csvBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("myfile.csv");
            var csvContent = new ByteArrayContent(csvBytes);
            content.Add(csvContent, "csvfile", "datafile.csv");

            HttpResponseMessage uploadResponse = await client.PostAsync("api/datasets", content);
```

However, the sever is now returning a message saying I have not specified the "name" parameter. What am I missing? How do I submit the parameters correctly?

Answer (score 1):

before content.Add(csvContent, "csvfile", "datafile.csv");
add these lines:

```
csvContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/csv");
csvContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"csvfile\"; filename=\"datafile.csv\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
new Dictionary<string, string> { { "name", "myName" }}
```

to

```
new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>({ "name", "myName" })
```

it should notice the param now.

Comment: hmmm. Still doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps there is something wrong on the sever side?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess:

To wrap up a series of key/value pairs, you should choose *either* application/x-www-form-urlencoded (FormUrlEncodedContent) *or* multipart/form-data (MultipartFormDataContent). If you use both then you're creating two levels of boxes.

Specifically, the API you're calling almost certainly wants

```
  multipart/form-data
    subpart with name "parameter1" value "value1"
    subpart with name "parameter2" value "value2"
    subpart with name "csvfile" value <contents of datafile.csv>
```

but you're giving it

```
  multipart/form-data
    subpart with no name, value "parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2", content-type x-www-form-urlencoded
    subpart with name "csvfile" value <contents of datafile.csv>
```

See [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273) for a more complete explanation of the two ways of returning form data.